Why is there no option to flag as spam in Staging Ground?
I came across an obvious spam question in Staging Ground.
However, there is no option to flag as Spam. Yeah, you could flag as "Not about Programming", but that doesn't feel specific enough for me.

You can raise spam flags on Staging Ground.

Quoting Abdul Aziz Barkat, from comments:

Flags are separate from the review actions you can take, it's probably not counted as a review to keep your flags private. Just flag the post and move on to another one by skipping or opening it from the SG listing


But I cant in the review Queue

What "review queue" you mean? You mention staging ground in your question. As you can see in the screenshot above, that question is on Staging Ground.

@BendingRodriguez flags are separate from the review actions you can take, it's probably not counted as a review to keep your flags private. Just flag the post and move on to another one by skipping or opening it from the SG listing

Slightly off topic, but is it expected that flagging as spam does not count as a review action?

@ray abdul already gave a possible and very valid reason why this is not the case. But on top of that... spam should never enter the staging ground and thus never be up for review. The spam link in the staging ground is essentially a necessary evil only.

Thanks for @Gimby and Abdul's clarification. I now understand from your perspective. I was thinking about LQ review queue's audit item, which flagging spam counts as one review item. I feel like if we have spent time on one review item, then it should count. Nevertheless, the fact that flagging in SG doesn't count actually does not bother me much and I am ok with your explanation :)
